# Get selected value from drop down and pass selected value into submit button in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have two drop down from two different array.

i want to get/store selected value from drop down. so that i can pass/send selected value in submit button (href)

Example:supoose user select email as 123 and center as "training",so i need to pass thoes two value in submit button like below-

```html
<main role="main">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h4 class="heading-theme  page-header pdt">Create Email Template</h4>
         <span class="border-bottom display-block mb-20"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mb-3">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
         <select class="custom-select" id="status" title="Status">
            <option value="" selected>Select  Template</option>
            <?php
               foreach ($emailTemplate as $row) {
               ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['temp_desc'] ?>"><?= $row['temp_desc'] ?></option>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
         <select class="custom-select" id="status" title="Status">
            <option value="" selected>Select  Center</option>
            <?php
               foreach ($trainingCenter as $row) {
               ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['organization_name'] ?>"><?= $row['organization_name'] ?></option>
            <?php
               }
               ?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="mt-2"><a href=" /Mycenter/testmailtemplate/value1/value2" class="text-default btn btn-sm pri-btn pt-2 mr-3 ">
            Submit
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You can get data from selections and send ajax request (if I correctly understand what you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both selected values using `each` loop inside some variable then split that values and finally add them to `href` of your  tag.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var values = "";
  //traverse through all selects
  $(".status").each(function() {
    //separate values using "."
    values += $(this).val() + ".";
  })
  //split values
  var new_values = values.split(".");
  var select_text= $('#status :selected').text();//getting selected text
  $new_href = "/Mycenter/testmailtemplate/" + new_values[0] + "/" + new_values[1]+"/"+ select_text;
  //add value to your href
  $(".pri-btn").attr("href", $new_href)
  console.log($new_href)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4 class="heading-theme  page-header pdt">Create Email Template</h4>
      <span class="border-bottom display-block mb-20"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
      <!--added class="status"-->
      <select class="custom-select status" id="status" title="Status">
        <option value="" selected>Select Template</option>
        <option value="1">1th</option>
        <option value="2">2th</option>
        <option value="3">3th</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
      <!--added class="status"-->
      <select class="custom-select status" title="Status">
        <option value="" selected>Select Center</option>
        <option value="1">
          1</option>
        <option value="2">
          2</option>
        <option value="3">3
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-2"><a href=" /Mycenter/testmailtemplate/value1/value2" class="text-default btn btn-sm pri-btn pt-2 mr-3 ">
            Submit
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: its really helpful but how to use new URL($new_href) in  html,in create button.Because i want to add these selected value in html URL so i can fetch these value in controller.

Comment: using `$(".pri-btn").attr("href", $new_href)` already changed the `href` with `$new_href` of your submit button .you can check that just hover on your `a` tag .

Comment: its working Perfectly..just need one more thing,i want to send one more value from drop down1.

suppose i have selected value="1" so getting the value as 1.,need to send name of this value also.

Example  <option value="1">TestCenter</option>

new UrL Should be 
/Mycenter/testmailtemplate/1/2/TestCenter

my URl should append valueFromDropdown1/valueFromDropdown2/NameFromValue1.is it possible to achive in above code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  

    $(".custom-select").on("change", function() {
 var value1 = $("#status1").val();
var value2 = $("#status2").val();
   
var url = '/Mycenter/testmailtemplate/'+value1+'/'+value2;
  $(".pri-btn").attr("href", url );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4 class="heading-theme  page-header pdt">Create Email Template</h4>
      <span class="border-bottom display-block mb-20"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
      <!--added class="status"-->
      <select class="custom-select status" id="status1" title="Status">
        <option value="" selected>Select Template</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 mb-1">
      <!--added class="status"-->
      <select class="custom-select status" id="status2" title="Status">
        <option value="" selected>Select Center</option>
        <option value="1">
          1</option>
        <option value="2">
          2</option>
        <option value="3">3
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-2"><a href=" /Mycenter/testmailtemplate/value1/value2" class="text-default btn btn-sm pri-btn pt-2 mr-3 ">
            Submit
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
```